# Android Studio: Newly added module is not showing in Project Structure window

Tags: android, gradle, unityads

I am trying to integrate `UnityAds` in my `Android Studio` project.

And for that `unity-ads.aar` package needs to be added as a module and in the later part, that module must be added as a dependency.

I have successfully added the `unity-ads.aar` package as a `module` but when I go to the `Project Structure`-> `Dependencies`.
There's no `unity-ads` below the `<All Modules>`. Only the `app` module is present.

According to the documentation the `unity-ads` should be present on that window from where I will be able to add that `unity-ads` as a `dependency` in my project.

[image: This picture will help to understand the problem]

What could be the problem????

How can I add that module as a dependency in my project???

Answer (score 0):

To add the unity-ads.aar module in your app.

[Download latest version here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/unity-ads-android/releases)

After the download extract it anywhere you want.

open your project.
Go to File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies (add new dependency)[image]

Select import jar/aar package.
[image]

Give the path of the unity-ads.aar file.
Click ok and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Open `settings.gradle` and add the missing line:

```
include :unity-ads3.7.1
```